# Excel VBA - Inserting column of data at point of function input

Tags: excel, vba

I am faced with creating a document in excel that requires repetitive instances of the same column of data at multiple points in the sheet, but they arent in 'regular' intervals - so i would like to have a function to both insert new rows and paste the data based on the current active cell (the cell into which i put in the function, or similar). Based on some basic googling it felt like it should be fairly simple with some Range commands, but the farthest ive gotten is #value! instead of compile issues. Guessing it is due to the range functions not quite being set up correctly in my code

```vb
Sub insertcopy()
Range(Sheet2!A2, Sheet2!A82).Copy
Range.Insert
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range.Insert` - do you want `ActiveCell` instead of `Range`?

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A82").Copy`?

Comment: Thanks Ben  - i am trying to copy the Range on Sheet 2 (essentially just 1 column of 100 rows) and paste it while expanding the rows to fit the lines needed for the paste-in. Would it be Activecell.insert? or something else?

Comment: You may want to record a macro here... it should give you most of what you need I would think.

Comment: thanks - yea it seems like that is simple enough.